# MS crm Account Creation: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using 
I am logged into a remote server for accessing Visual studio as well as MS CRM. I have taken sample code from SDK and trying to run the code:

```
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();

token.AuthenticationType = 0;

token.OrganizationName = "AdventureWorksCycle";

CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Url= "http://10.16.16.205:5555/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx";
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;

service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential"username", "password", "domain");

// Create the account object.
account account = new account();

// Set the properties of the account object.
account.name = "Fourth Coffee123";
account.address1_line1 = "29 Market St.";
account.address1_city = "Sam";
account.address1_stateorprovince = "MT1";
account.address1_postalcode = "9999";
account.donotbulkemail = new CrmBoolean();
account.donotbulkemail.Value = true;

// Create the target object for the request.
TargetCreateAccount target = new TargetCreateAccount();

// Set the properties of the target object.
target.Account = account;

// Create the request object.
CreateRequest create = new CreateRequest();

// Set the properties of the request object.
create.Target = target;

// Execute the request.
CreateResponse created = (CreateResponse)service.Execute(create);
```

I am using Crm Web Service for this, but Its throwing exception:

Exception Details:

> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   failed with HTTP status 401:
>   Unauthorized.
>
> Source Error:

`Line 114:        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Response")]`

`Line 115:        public Response Execute(Request Request) {`

`Line 116:            ***object[] results = this.Invoke("Execute", new object[]* {**`

`Line 117:                        Request});`

`Line 118:            return ((Response)(results[0]));`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are missing is a real username and password. I am assuming that you have omitted this for the purposes of this question.

Have you checked the security role on the user that you are using for the web service call? Add this user to the System Administrator role if you haven't already.

With CRM often times, this error has nothing to do with security but something else altogether.

First turn on CRM tracing and look there. This will give you more error detail. Here's how:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490

Also you can try to use my exception formatter to get more detail on the error. This is an extension class that will allow you to format the exception and print it to stdout or to the http response. Find it here:
http://paste.ly/5Y66

Use it this way:

```
try {
   // do all your stuff
} catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.Print();
}
```

Notice that in the formatted exception output, you can see the "Details" property deserialized such that you can see the text version. This is where CRM hides the real exception most of the time.